# Is it possible to create a row containing totals for some columns and averages for others?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe dealing with time series data in which some some columns represent amounts, and some columns represent percentages. I want a row which summarizes each column, but obviously it is not particularly useful for me to sum the columns containing percentages.

Here is an example dataframe:

```r
date<-c("2019-04-27", "2019-04-28", "2019-05-01")
name<-c("sam", "sam", "sam")
amt1<-c(3,6,2)
amt2<-c(4,2,7)
percent1<-c(0.25, 0.7, 0.42)
amt3<-c(13,7,4)
percent2<-c(0.54, 0.48, 0.77)

df<-data.frame(date,name, amt1, amt2, percent1, amt3, percent2)
df$date<-as.Date(df$date)
```

What I would like is a row that contains:

-the sums for columns amt1, amt2, amt3

-the means for columns percent1, percent2.

Anyone have any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: You want a row or two columns?

Comment: OK, are the `amt` columns of type integer and the `percent` columns of type double, or both just numeric?

Comment: I'm looking for a row. 

Both are numeric

Comment: One way to look would be if there are decimals in 'amt'.  With the example you provided, it is not.  If there are floating points in original data, it is difficult to distingish from percent.  Or another idea is that the percent range from 0 to 1.  Is that the case

Comment: @akrun All "amt" values are whole numbers and could be integers if this makes the solution easier. 

The percentages all ranges from 0-1, yes.

Apologies if this is very basic. I am a complete beginner

Comment: @AlexSheppard  I updated solution.  Can you check it now

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to select the `numeric` columns (`select_if`), then using `mutate_if`, get the `mean` of those columns where the values are `all` less than 1, in the next step, do the `sum` of columns where there are `any` value greater than 1.  (Disclaimer - The OP said there are no column name patterns or index and this is one of the possible logic given by the OP)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  mutate_if(~ all(.x < 1), mean) %>%
  mutate_if(~ any(.x > 1), sum) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .) %>%
  mutate(name = replace(as.character(name), n(), "Other"))
#         date  name amt1 amt2  percent1 amt3  percent2
#1 2019-04-27   sam    3    4 0.2500000   13 0.5400000
#2 2019-04-28   sam    6    2 0.7000000    7 0.4800000
#3 2019-05-01   sam    2    7 0.4200000    4 0.7700000
#4       <NA> Other   11   13 0.4566667   24 0.5966667
```

Comment: Ah, this is an oversight on my part. My actual dataframe is much larger and there is no pattern in the column names.

Comment: @AlexSheppard  Would there be column index like 1:5 would be 'amt' columns ?

Comment: @AlexSheppard  Is it a condition that there is no pattern in column names and not similarity in columns adjacent to each other (completely random) and you want to create a program that automatically finds - it could be 'amt' and other 'percent' column?

Comment: @AlexSheppard  Please clarify if you can.

Comment: Yes, basically the dataset as I received it was completely random. They are not adjacent, and have no pattern in name.

If this is impossible without restructuring the dataframe so that amounts are adjacent and percentages are adjacent, then I would be open to solutions which involve that structure.

Comment: @AlexSheppard  If there is no pattern, and you can't find which one is 'am't or 'percent', then it is difficult for the software to decipher as welll.  There must be some logic to separate both

Comment: This is great. Trying to wrap my head around how it works now, but it does exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.